# websocket connection over TLS using nopoll fails with SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Tags: tls, openssl, websocket

I am writing a messaging client that should connect to a server using websocket secure(WSS). When the client initiates nopoll connection, openssl returns SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL.

The server also supports https-sse protocol. So, to confirm that the x.509 certificates used are correct, I tried connecting to the server using https-sse. This works as expected.

Since the server uses the same certificates to authenticate clients connecting over wss or https, I don't understand why wss connection would fail with SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL when https connection can work with the same server.

Server ip address and port number are the same of WSS and HTTPS. They differ only in the schema. wss://: and https://:
Client supporting both wss and https is written in C language as it is intended to be an existing product running code written in C.

Comment: I think this is missing enough details to answer. Do both protocols use the same target name *and port*, i.e. differ only between https and wss? Do you access both URL's with the same client (browser, app...)?  Can you provide the URL's for both https and wss in case they are public? And if not - can you provide packet captures (as full pcap, maybe at cloudshark.org) for successful (https) and unsuccessful (wss) connection?

Comment: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL is an internal error and is not related to security.   Perhaps ask at Serverfault or Stackoverflow, whichever is more relevant to your question.

Comment: @OskarSkog: this error often comes if the server or a firewall closes the connection with RESET. This can for example happen because of specifics of the TLS handshake and thus might be related to security. But it is hard to tell with only the few information provided. Serverfault and Stackoverflow will not be able to help here too simply because information are missing to reproduce or further look at the issue.

Comment: Ah, right.  That would cause a syscall to fail.  Didn't expect an external failure.

Comment: Given that the OP did not add any additionally requested information to the page so far I propose it as too broad since it cannot be answered based on the provided information alone.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have edited the description with answers to first 2 questions from you.

Comment: Server is running in a private network.

Comment: @Kumar: if https:// and wss:// both share the code and target for the TLS handshake I doubt that the problem is the handshake. Instead I suspect  a problem in the implementation of WebSockets on client or server which causes the server to crash or close the connection. Alternatively it might be a SSL interception proxy which does not understand WebSockets and thus closes the connection. Packet captures, information about network setup (i.e. if there some SSL intercepting firewall or similar) and information about server behavior (any logs indicating error?) might help to track down the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The websocket client process used nopoll library that needed access to /dev/urandom as it called random() to generate seed. But the process itself was running in a linux container that did not have access to /dev/urandom. So the client was unable to generate keys during TLS handshake.

Mounting /dev/urandom to the client container resolved the issue.